# Reload Json content in MVVM and WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a Model called FieldModel. In ViewModel I am setting its properties through a json file parsing like this:

```
foreach (var field in innerClass.Item2.Properties)
                    {
                        FieldView fieldView = new FieldView(field);
                        fieldView.ClassName = classView.ClassName; 
                        fieldView.IsAbstract = classView.IsAbstract;
                        FieldViewItems.Add(fieldView);
                    }
```

My question is: how to make the binding properly with the reload button in order to reload the content of json file when it's being modified ?

Comment: Is your `FieldViewItems` a property with a backing field? And is it raising `PropertyChanged` event?

Comment: it s an ObservableCollection<FieldView>. FieldView is my model

Comment: You can use a `FileSystemWatcher` to automatically monitor the file for changes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First implement a Command class, I prefer something like this :

```
public class GeneralCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action ToBeExecutedAction;
    private Func<bool> ExecutionValidatorFunc;

    public GeneralCommand(Action toBeExecutedAction, Func<bool> executionValidatorFunc)
    {
        ToBeExecutedAction = toBeExecutedAction;
        ExecutionValidatorFunc = executionValidatorFunc;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return ExecutionValidatorFunc();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        ToBeExecutedAction();
    }
}
```

Now inside your ViewModel class, implement something like the following :

```
public class FieldModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private GeneralCommand _generalCommand;

    public FieldModel()
    {
        Action action = new Action(ChangeValue);
        _generalCommand = new GeneralCommand(action, new Func<bool>(() => true));
    }

    public ICommand ReloadValues
    {
        get
        {
            return _generalCommand;
        }
    }

    string _jsonText;
    public string JsonText
    {
        get
        {
            return _jsonText;
        }
    }

    private void ChangeValue()
    {
        //Change JsonText here 

        //Then raise event change to be updated
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TextJson"));//Here fill property name
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Then from the Xaml bind your Reload button into command property `ReloadValues` inside your ViewModel object, and bind the `JsonText` property with a WPF control for example a `Textbox`.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: and by writing: PropertyChangedEventArgs("PropertyName") the property(or properties) changed is(are) properly field ?

Comment: OK. but what if : "//Change JsonText here " is happening by opening the json file and its not happening in C# code ? is the approach still  good ?

Comment: If you mean it can be changed from outside code, when Reload button is clicked each time Re-open the file and display its content